# The role assignment already exists error displayed after implementing retry logic

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to assign role to web app after set the system assigned managed identity. The problem is it throw error if you assign role just after the set the managed identity.

```
2019-04-04T07:57:12.9852397Z ##[error]Principal 438350e59xxxxxxxxxx935e5c135 does not exist in the directory ***.
```

So I added retry code to try assign role till the principal available.

```
$webappname = "devt002"
$resourcegroup = "devt002RG"
$roleDefinitionName = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"

#Set the system assigned managed identity
Set-AzureRmWebApp -AssignIdentity $true -ResourceGroupName "$resourcegroup" -Name "$webappname"

#Get webapp object id
$webapp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "$resourcegroup" -Name "$webappname"
$objectid = [System.Guid]::Parse($webapp.Identity.PrincipalId)
write-host "Object ID :" $objectid

#Get resource id (Scope) for storage account
$webapp2 = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "$resourcegroup" -Name "$webappname" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
$resid = $webapp2.ResourceId.ToString()
write-host "Resource ID :" $resid

#Get Assign role if already exist
$roles = Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId "$objectid"
write-host "Already Assigned Roles :" $roles.RoleDefinitionName

if($roles.RoleDefinitionName -Match "Storage Blob Data Contributor")
{
    Write-Host "Storage Blob Data Contributor role already exist !!!"
}
else
{
    #Assign role to web app (Object id)
    $retryCount = 5
    $totalRetries = $retryCount
    While ($True) 
    {
        Try 
        {
            $Null = New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objectid -RoleDefinitionName "$roleDefinitionName" -Scope "$resid"
            Write-Host "Storage Blob Data Contributor role assign successfully !!!"
            Return
        }
        Catch 
        {
            # The principal could not be found. Maybe it was just created.
            If ($retryCount -eq 0) 
            {
                Write-Error "An error occurred: $($_.Exception)`n$($_.ScriptStackTrace)"
                throw "The principal '$objectId' cannot be granted '$roleDefinitionName' role on the web app '$webappname'. Please make sure the principal exists and try again later."
            }
            $retryCount--
            Write-Warning "  The principal '$objectId' cannot be granted '$roleDefinitionName' role on the web app '$webappname'. Trying again (attempt $($totalRetries - $retryCount)/$totalRetries)"
            Start-Sleep 10
        }
    }

}
```

but this time below error occured. Strange thing is role is assigned to the web app.

```
2019-04-04T10:00:58.8423494Z Object ID : 31d52967-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b3944da09ab2
2019-04-04T10:01:02.6524758Z Resource ID : /subscriptions/4364666b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-47158904c439/resourceGroups/devt002RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/devt002
2019-04-04T10:01:04.2157521Z Already Assigned Roles : 
2019-04-04T10:01:14.1407666Z ##[warning]  The principal '31d52967-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b3944da09ab2' cannot be granted 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the web app 'devt002'. Trying again (attempt 1/5)
2019-04-04T10:01:14.1417125Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]  The principal '31d52967-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b3944da09ab2' cannot be granted 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the web app 'devt002'. Trying again (attempt 1/5)
2019-04-04T10:01:25.7075458Z ##[warning]  The principal '31d52967-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b3944da09ab2' cannot be granted 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the web app 'devt002'. Trying again (attempt 2/5)
2019-04-04T10:01:25.7076201Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]  The principal '31d52967-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b3944da09ab2' cannot be granted 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the web app 'devt002'. Trying again (attempt 2/5)
2019-04-04T10:01:37.5640393Z ##[warning]  The principal '31d52967-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b3944da09ab2' cannot be granted 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the web app 'devt002'. Trying again (attempt 3/5)
2019-04-04T10:01:37.5640997Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]  The principal '31d52967-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b3944da09ab2' cannot be granted 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the web app 'devt002'. Trying again (attempt 3/5)
2019-04-04T10:01:50.5967259Z ##[warning]  The principal '31d52967-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b3944da09ab2' cannot be granted 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the web app 'devt002'. Trying again (attempt 4/5)
2019-04-04T10:01:50.5967755Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]  The principal '31d52967-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b3944da09ab2' cannot be granted 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the web app 'devt002'. Trying again (attempt 4/5)
2019-04-04T10:02:02.7386688Z ##[warning]  The principal '31d52967-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b3944da09ab2' cannot be granted 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the web app 'devt002'. Trying again (attempt 5/5)
2019-04-04T10:02:02.7387138Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]  The principal '31d52967-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b3944da09ab2' cannot be granted 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the web app 'devt002'. Trying again (attempt 5/5)
2019-04-04T10:02:16.4259863Z ##[error]An error occurred: Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: The role assignment already exists.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there should be something to make sure about the role assignment. For the same scope or resource, you can only assign the same role to a service principal once. In this case, it means you can only assign the role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" of the storage account to your app identity once.

So when you check if the role assignment exists, you can only need to check if the result of the PowerShell command is null or not.

```
Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId "$objectid" -RoleDefinitionName "$roleDefinitionName" -Scope "$resid"
```

And I think the while loop is not appropriate. If the role assignment can be created successfully, then it just needs one time. More then one time is meaningless. So you just need to check if it's successful. If not, then what is the reason.

**Update**

From your PowerShell script, I find that you use the command below to get the web app identity Id:

```
$objectid = [System.Guid]::Parse($webapp.Identity.PrincipalId)
```

It's not right. You just can get the result of an object, not just the Id. Like this:

[image]

Two ways to get just the Id.

One: `$webapp.Identity.PrincipalId`

Two: `$objectid.Guid`

I suggest the first way, then you can delete the command `$objectid = [System.Guid]::Parse($webapp.Identity.PrincipalId)`.

With your comment, the operation that enables the managed identity of the web app will take a while to make the effect. It's better to sleep a while before creating the role assignment than use the while loop. Not long, just sleep 30 secs is totally enough.

Comment: When this script run for the first time, the result will always be null. But problem is with managed identity not available instantly. This is the main reason behind calling while loop 5 times.

Comment: Thnks for the advice. You understand my issue?

Comment: @rAJ If you mean you cannot create the role assignment so you run it five times?

Comment: Let me explain it in detail. Intially there is no managed identity and role assignment. I run the script and it creates new managed identity. When role assignment code run it will fail because managed identity not activate instantly. It takes some time(probabily 30-40 sec). So i added while loop which try role assignment in 10 sec interval. So i am expecting in 3rd or 4th loop it should create role and get out from loop. Somehow when loop is running it creates role and not able to get out. After 5 counter completes it throw error that role already exist and breaks. There is issue in while loop

Comment: @rAJ OK, I get your purpose. But why don't you just sleep a while before you create the role assignment? It's more simple and useful.

Comment: Yes i am also thinking of it. Just need to find out the exact time when service identity is available.

Comment: @rAJ Just sleep 30 secs, it's enough.

Comment: Added. Start-Sleep -s 30

Comment: @rAJ Then you do not need the while loop. Do you succeed doing that?

Answer (score 7):

what its trying to tell you - the equivalent role assign exists with a different name and you cannot have the same assignment twice under different names.

So I guess the question is, why do you need to assign the same permission twice under a different name

Comment: Before running this code i make sure that there is no role assign to the web app and managed identity also not set. This code set the managed identity and then assign role. According to me after assigning role it should display the success message and get out of loop.

Comment: I dont have the time to look through your code now, can only do that in the evening, but thats what this error means

Comment: That i can assure you the role not present already. This code is assigning role. The problem is in the retry logic. It just not get out of the loop at the right time after doing its work. :)